# JavaScript return in functions - What to do with the undefined?

Tags: javascript, function

I study front-end.
I started creating the javascript side for Rock-Paper-Scissors project, with console.logs instead of applying results to the HTML.
I created the html with 3 buttons of the choices, and I created a new div to apply the results of the game (who chose what, and who wins).
I already added 2 paragraphs for the player and computer choices, but now I have the function, and I'm a bit stuck.

here is the js:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
const resultsDiv = document.querySelector('.results');

const getComputerChoice = () => {
  const options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  const computerChoice = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
  return computerChoice;
};

const playRound = (playerSelection, computerSelection) => {
  playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();

  const playerChoiceMsg = document.createElement('p');
  playerChoiceMsg.textContent = `You chose ${playerSelection}`
  resultsDiv.appendChild(playerChoiceMsg);

  const computerChoiceMsg = document.createElement('p');
  computerChoiceMsg.textContent = `Computer chose ${computerSelection}`;
  resultsDiv.appendChild(computerChoiceMsg)


  if (playerSelection === 'rock') {
    switch (computerSelection) {
      case 'rock':
        return 'Even! Try Again!';
      case 'paper':
        return 'You lose! Paper beats Rock!';
      case 'scissors':
        return 'You win! Scissors beats Rock!';
    }
  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper') {
    switch (computerSelection) {
      case 'rock':
        return 'You win! Paper beats Rock!';
      case 'paper':
        return 'Even! Try Again!';
      case 'scissors':
        return 'You lose! Scissors beats Paper!';
    }
  } else {
    // Player chose scissors
    switch (computerSelection) {
      case 'rock':
        return 'You lose! Rock beats Scissors!';
      case 'paper':
        return 'You win! Scissors beats Paper!';
      case 'scissors':
        return 'Even! Try Again!';
    }
  }
};

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const playerSelection = button.textContent;
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, getComputerChoice()));
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="btn btn-rock">Rock</button>
  <button class="btn btn-paper">Paper</button>
  <button class="btn btn-scissors">Scissors</button>
</div>

<div class="results">

</div>
```

In the switch cases, I can just create a new let to apply the result (win, lose, even) with a proper message, and then createElement(p) to apply it to the results div.
But, if I do this, I will get "undefined" in the DevTools, because the function won't return anything.
I know functions don't always have to return, but it doesn't look professional to see "undefined" (what would you think if it happens after clicking a button in Google?)
What is the best way to get rid of the undefined?
Should I just add "return;" to the end of the function?

Comment: Edited to use a snippet. It appears to work as expected.  Please indicate more clearly what's wrong, like where the unwanted "undefined" is found.

Answer (score 2):

> I know functions don't always have to return...

They don't have to have an explicit return statement.  But, they always return.  If you don't include a `return` statement, the function returns `undefined` after it executes.

> ...but it doesn't look professional to see "undefined" (what would you think if it happens after clicking a button in Google?)

Who cares?  :-)  The search works, right?

Sure, it's generally considered a poor practice to have stuff dumped in the console on public builds of your code, but it's just a tool like any other.  Use it when you find it useful.

> What is the best way to get rid of the undefined? Should I just add "return;" to the end of the function?

No, if you try this you'll see that you still get `undefined`.  If you don't want to output anything to console, just don't use `console.log()`.  Replace this line:

```
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, getComputerChoice()));
```

With this:

```
playRound(playerSelection, getComputerChoice());
```